# Make a hole in Photoshop vector shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a rounded rectangle vector shape. I would like to make a hole in it (B - A).

How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not so sure but I think you should check this [site](http://adobephotoshopsecrets.blogspot.com/2011/02/make-hole-in-shape.html)

Answer (score 5):

1. Make the top shape (AKA the "Hole") as a vector object then flatten it.
2. Then use the Magic Selection tool to select the flattened "Hole" shape
3. Next Invert the Selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>).
4. With your selection inverted, click on the Base Layer that should have the "Hole" in it.
5. With the Base Layer Selected, click on the Layer Mask button @ the bottom of your layers 
   panel.
6. This will open up the "Hole" in your Base Layer shape.

** I keep the flattened hole layer in case you want to use certain effects like a drop shadow or drop glow effect. You may have to use the flattened layer to achieve some of these effects as I just found out.

Please Note: There may be a better way to do this, but this method worked for my needs. Good luck all!

Answer (score 0):

duplicate question to this one:

[Cut/knock one shape out of another shape](https://superuser.com/questions/396758/cut-knock-one-shape-out-of-another-shape/396820#396820)

in the same layer: in essence, either flatten the vector mask, and do the knockout on a new vector mask, or use a layer mask (because you can't have another vector mask on the same layer)